# Is right hand rule arbitrary?

Tags: vectors, conventions, coordinate-systems, geometry, mathematics

In definition of vector multiplication, the direction of the resulting vector is given by the right hand rule. However I don't know any mathematical requirement to pick right hand instead of left for this purpose. Is there any?

Comment: Is the right-handedness definition of vector math arbitrary?  Yes.

Comment: Thanks. As a follow up question, why the right hand?

Comment: Anecdotally, Eugene Wigner used the left hand rule for his calculations, converting as appropriate for the final answer. But then, he did know a little about group theory and symmetries and how to convert them in his head...

Comment: Again anecdotally (from grad school 30+ years ago): Wigner compromised to use right-handed coordinates if the German prefix $eigen$ was maintained as the prefix versus "characteristic." That may be totally bogus, but it makes for a good story in class.

Comment: It depends on whether you use a right-handed or left-handed coordinate system. Once you pick the relative directions of X, Y and Z, the rest follows.

Comment: @Floris So the right hand rule isn't arbitrary, it's a result of relative directions of axes, and what is really arbitrary is the relative directions of axes?

Comment: @user144302 yes, I would say so.

Comment: @Floris Thank you. In this ( https://www.evl.uic.edu/ralph/508S98/coordinates.html ) page, I see the fundamental difference between a right-handed coordinate system and a left-handed one is the direction of positive rotation. It is cw for a left-handed cor.sys. and ccw for a right-handed cs

Comment: @Floris Therefore the direction of positive rotation influences the definition of vectorial multiplication. May I ask how?

Comment: @Floris If the comments above are complicated. To put simply, why is the resulting vector in a multiplication perpendicular to both of the vectors that are multiplied? Is there even a reason for that, let alone the right hand rule?

Comment: The definition of vector multiplication: it is the vector that is perpendicular to the plane created by the two vectors being multiplied, with a length proportional to the area of the triangle formed by those two vectors. Once you define it that way, you should be able to prove that the equation (the mechanics of calculating it) follows from the definition.

Comment: @Floris Calculations are easy to understand once a definition is made. It's the definition that I am asking about. It feels incredibly arbitrary. Is it really? Who defined it that way, and why? Is there any reason why I shouldn't make my own definition? Usually mathematics prohibit that because the definition of interest is tightly related to simpler concepts. However in this case, I see no relations, no basic concepts, no prohibition.

Comment: @user144302 - I always found the "volume concept" of the dot and cross products helpful. The volume of an object formed by vectors A,B,C is $(A\times B)\cdot C$. Nice explanation is given [on the mathexchange site](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/62318/101979) where this question was asked before...

Comment: @Floris Thank you. This answer taught me a lot of keywords. And your understanding really seem to be compliant with three dimensional systems so also thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define it with the left hand, too. In this case, the formula of the 3d vectorial multiplication would simply negated.

A physics could be also constructed for that, it would be exactly the same, of course the formulas using vectorial multiplication would be negated.

It is like a binary Higgs-mechanism, similarly as the analog, mechanical clocks are rotating to right. They could rotate also left. Some hundreds of years ago, a lot of them did.

Comment: Sundials, south of the equator, still do go CCW.

Comment: @Whit3rd It is because the world would work exactly as before, only our formulas would change.

Answer (score 4):

Draw a 3D set of axis for XYZ. Where is positive X? Where is positive Y? Where is positive Z? Obviously wherever you want them but right, up and out of the page are the commonly accepted choices.

Now accepting that how do I remember it? I close the fingers of my right hand from X to Y and my thumb points to Z. If I instead preferred opening my fingers from X to Y I would use need to use my left hand.

Also this lets teachers be pretty sure who is going to fail during tests.

EDIT:
The relation of the orientations is part of the definition of a cross product. We want to avoid adding negative signs if we don't have to. Using the traditional XYZ this means closing your right hand, but each time you flip the sign of an axis you can add a switch of hands to preserve a "stay positive" property.

Comment: I understand how x,y and z are arbitrarily picked when representing on paper. However there could still be a requirement for a certain directional relationship between vectors AxB=C. And thats what I was asking. Turns out there isn't any, with the help of previous answers.